# Merge similar elements of a list in one new list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python list:

```
A = [1 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 1 , 4 , 1]
```

I want to merge similar elements in a new list and put all separate lists in one other list.

For example , the output for the above input should be:

```
 [[1 , 1 ,1] , [2 ,2] , [3] , [4]]
```

Order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the values, and generate the sublists in a list comprehension:

```
from collections import Counter

A = [1 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 1 , 4 , 1]

out = [[item]*count for item, count in Counter(A).items()]
print(out)
# [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2], [3], [4]]
```

Comment: Nice solution. Worth commenting this is an O(n) solution, while pre-sorting (the alternative) is O(n log n).

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.groupby` to group elements:

```
from itertools import groupby

A = [1 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 1 , 4 , 1]

print([list(g) for _, g in groupby(sorted(A))])
# [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2], [3], [4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [1 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 1 , 4 , 1]

dct = defaultdict(list)
for i in lst:
    dct[i].append(i)

print(list(dct.values()))
# [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2], [3], [4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arrayA = [1 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 1 , 4 , 1]
setS = set(arrayA)
finalArray = []
for i in setS:
    tempArray = []
    for j in range(arrayA.count(i)):
        tempArray.append(i) 
    finalArray.append(tempArray)

print (finalArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort then push to an array.

```
A.sort()
ans = [[]]
for num in A:
    if ans[-1] and ans[-1][-1] == num:
        ans[-1] += [num]
    else:
        ans += [[num]]
print(ans)
```